# Best way to test changes in silverlight application

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

which is the best way to rebuild a silverlight project in Visual Studio 2010? I ask because I happen to be a rebuild and I do not take effect the changes I made in a xaml and a. cs file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding ought to be doing the trick. If the changes you're making in your project are not being reflected when you build, try clicking "Build > Clean Solution" before you rebuild. If that doesn't work, restart Visual Studio.

Comment: ...and if that doesn't work, you're not rebuilding what you think you're rebuilding. Double-check the file paths to ensure you're editing the right files.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably rebuild but not running the newest XAP.

How are you testing the app?  From with in Visual Studio (F5) or from a published website?

If from the Visual check associated the ASP project's properties for where the Silverlight XAP is going. Check the test page is using the correct XAP.  Check the date\time of that XAP.

If from a published website perhaps the XAP isn't being put in the correct location in the site... check the date\time of the XAP there.

Also perhaps delete the web browser cache.